# Neofetch shows resolution that is higher than set on PopOS 22.04

Tags: linux, debian, ubuntu, resolution, pop-os

When I run neofetch in terminal on PopOS 22.04, it says that my resolution is 3072x1728. However, my resolution is set to 1920x1080 in settings, fractional scaling is turned on and scale factor is 125%. What should I do?

Comment: Do you use a multimonitor setup?

Comment: @BlueManCZ no, it probably was because of fractional scaling